# FileSaver downloading corrupted ZIP file

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, zip, filesaver.js

My front-end code (react) gets a response from my backend (node) and downloads a zip file as expected but the zip file, when clicked, will produce a CPGZ file instead instead of decompressing the zip.

**React Code**

```
downloadResultsFile() {

 fetch(`https://XXXXXXXX/api/download-results-file?jobName=${this.props.selectedRun.jobs[0].env.MIC_JOB_ID}`, {
  origin: 'same-origin', 
})
.then((res) => res.blob())
.then((file) =>  FileSaver.saveAs(file, this.props.selectedRun.jobs[0].env.MIC_JOB_ID + '-results.zip'));   


}
```

**Node Code**

```
downloadResults: function(app, s3){
app.use('/api', apiRoutes)

apiRoutes.get('/download-results-file', function(req, res, next){
   res.set({'Content-type': 'text/plain'})

   var params = {
    Bucket: 'xxxxx',
    Delimiter: '/',
    Prefix: 'xxxxxx'
   };


   var filesArray = []
   var files = s3.listObjectsV2(params).createReadStream()
   var xml = new XmlStream(files)
   xml.collect('Key')

   xml.on('endElement: Key', function(item) {
     filesArray.push(item['$text'].substr(params.Prefix.length))
    })

   var data = zip(filesArray, req.query.jobName, params)
   xml.on('end', function() {

    res.send(data.toString())

  })        
})
}
```

When I `console.log(res)` on the front-end I get a "writeable stream" for an object. I convert that into a blob and then I use FileSaver to create the zip file. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: This fix seems to be resolving the problem https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/issues/156

Answer (score 1):

Your backend sends a zip file, not a text file. Don't use `'Content-type': 'text/plain'`, use `'Content-type': 'application/zip'` or `'Content-type': 'application/octet-stream'` instead.

What does `zip(...)` returns ? I would expect a nodejs buffer. If so, `res.send(data.toString())` will decode your content from UTF-8 ([the default encoding](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_tostring_encoding_start_end)). Since it's not a text but a binary content, you will corrupt your content here. Instead, use `res.send(data)`.